# Regex to match digit-like but not pure-digit strings

Tags: regex

Let's say I have two character classes, `[1234]` (call it "pure digits") and `[⓵⓶⓷⓸]` (call it "funky digits"). I can create a mixed character class like `[1234⓵⓶⓷⓸]+`(call it "digit-like") that matches one or more pure or funky digits.

But I'd like to be able to match only digit-like strings with at least one funky digit. That is, match strings like `⓵2⓷4`, `123⓸`, and `⓵⓶⓷⓸` but *not* match a pure-digit string like `1234`.

Can you think of a way to express that as a regular expression?

Comment: Can't you use `\d*\D+\d*`?

Comment: Begin your pattern with positive lookahead `^(?=.*[⓵⓶⓷⓸])[1234⓵⓶⓷⓸]+`

Comment: What is the programming language/regex library? Are you extracting substrings from a large text? Replacing?

Comment: `[⓵-⓾]` is the character class for those digits.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew PCRE. Simply matching, not extracting substrings or replacing.

Comment: @Xufox I hadn't thought to try those symbols as a range!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pcre (or any regex engine that supports possessive quantifiers) you can do that:

```
/[1234]*+[1234⓵⓶⓷⓸]+/u
```

The possessive quantifier `*+` forbids backtracking, in this case you are sure that there's at least one special digit (since the next digit can only be one of the special digits that are not in the first character class).

Note that to handle this kind of multibyte characters, you have to use the u modifier.

Comment: This will match `1234`

Comment: Is that because of `*+`?

Comment: @Barmar: yes only because of that. It consumes all ascii digits and doesn't allow to backtrack, then the first character matched by `[1234⓵⓶⓷⓸]+` can only be a special digit.

Comment: Why does it match `⓸1`? It looks like you require at least non-funky digit to be before a funky digit.

Comment: @Barmar: https://regex101.com/r/KyuX8u/2 . The possessive quantifier is `*+` not `++`

Comment: I see. It's not like a lookbehind, it doesn't require the match. But if the whole string matches `[1234]*`, that consumes everything, and there's nothing to match `[1234⓵⓶⓷⓸]+` because it can't back up.

Comment: @Barmar: indeed, and in this case `1234⓵⓶⓷⓸]+` fails because there are no more characters to consume.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks! That's just what I was looking for. It's elegant, simple, and no worry about pathologic behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Because we don't know where in the sequence the funky digit will be, we need to both start and end the expression with the digit-like expression of arbitrary size, `[1234⓵⓶⓷⓸]*`.

As there is required to be at least one funky digit we will also need to match at least one symbol that is required to be funky, `[⓵⓶⓷⓸]`.

As such, our resulting expression is `[1234⓵⓶⓷⓸]*[⓵⓶⓷⓸][1234⓵⓶⓷⓸]*`.

Comment: This also works, and is simple. I like the possessive quantifier solution better because it prevents backtracking. For longer pure strings, the number of "steps" reported by regex101 balloons compared with `*+` solution (example: https://regex101.com/r/KyuX8u/3). Thanks for your answer.